# Proxy pass from HTTP to HTTPS is failing with bad gateway error "502"

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, httpserver, bad-gateway

I am trying pass HTTP from Oracle HTTP (OHS) to External, works via non-ssl, However, SSL is a bit challenging "OHS---NON-SSL--->External System(ssl)", and via SSL I am seeing "  " error need some light on this.

Errors seen in ohs logs:

```
[] [OHS] [ERROR:32] [] [core.c] [host_id: xxxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx] [host_addr: aa.aa.a.aaa] [tid: ] [user: oracle] [ecid:] [rid: 0] [VirtualHost: zzzzzzzzz:bbbb]  NZ Library Error: SSL fatal alert

[] [OHS] [ERROR:32] [] [core.c] [host_id: xxxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx] [host_addr: aa.aa.a.aaa] [tid: ] [user: oracle] [ecid: ] [rid: 0] [VirtualHost: zzzzzzzzz:bbbb] (20014)Internal error:  : pass  body failed to xx.xx.x.xxx:cccc (dddddddddddd.ddd.dddd)

[] [OHS] [ERROR:32] [] [core.c] [host_id: xxxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx] [host_addr: aa.aa.a.aaa] [tid: ] [user: oracle] [ecid: ] [rid: 0] [VirtualHost: zzzzzzzzz:bbbb]  : pass  body failed to xx.xx.x.xxx:cccc (dddddddddddd.ddd.dddd) from yy.yy.yy.yyy ()
```

Pass used in

```
 <IfModule mod_proxy.c> 
  SSLProxyEngine On 
  SSLPROXYWALLET "/zzz/zzzzzz/zzzzzzzzWallet" 
  ProxyPass / https://###.###.#####.######:XXXX/sss/aaa.sddd.sss.dddd/XXXX
  ProxyPassReverse / https://###.###.#####.######:XXXX/sss/aaa.sddd.sss.dddd/XXXX
  ProxyPreserveHost On 
  ProxyRequests off 
  </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think port 443 has been blocked in firewall level..just check whether port is opened or not by using netstat command.

Comment: I am not using port 443, I am using a different port.